# Azure - retrieving bicep module from container registry by major version

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry, azure-bicep

I have the repositories in my Azure Container Registry

- myregistry.azurecr.io/bicep/myappmodule:v1.0.25798
- myregistry.azurecr.io/bicep/myappmodule:v1.0.**25799**

I would like to reference the latest module by the Major Version (v1) in an external bicep file. So in this case the module with version v1.0.**25799** should be used.

**main.bicep:**

```
...
module appService 'br:myregistry.azurecr.io/bicep/myappmodule:v1' = {
  name: 'appService'
  params: {
    ...
  }
}
...
```

Is there a way to get the latest repository Version?

I tried without success:

- br:myregistry.azurecr.io/bicep/myappmodule:v1.*
- br:myregistry.azurecr.io/bicep/myappmodule:v1*
- br:myregistry.azurecr.io/bicep/myappmodule:v1:latest
- br:myregistry.azurecr.io/bicep/myappmodule:latest

Comment: I added it as an idea in the corresponding Azure/Bicep GitHub repository: 
https://github.com/Azure/bicep/discussions/7043

Comment: For deployment you better stay away from 'latest versions' because you are not sure you use the same resources on a redeploy:
"Avoid deployments with stable tags, because those tags continue to receive updates and can introduce inconsistencies in production environments." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-image-tag-version#stable-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom line why **this isn't possible at the moment**:
https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/4186#issuecomment-907600100

*There some interesting complexities if we supported version ranges rather than single versions:*

> - Every module restore that uses a version range would require an additional LIST call to enumerate tags in an ACR repository before downloading the module content.
> - Local caching benefits would be reduced a bit as well because we always have to query to check if there's a newer version that falls within the requested range.
> - bicep build becomes non-deterministic. Running it once and then another time could produce two different results if new module was published. NPM and NuGet solve this problem via lock files that get committed side by side with the source.
> - Not all versions/tags follow the x.y.z format.
> - The compiled JSON that gets published to the registry contains all the dependencies as they were resolved during bicep publish. Even if you rev'd one of the dependencies, nothing will change until the module is re-published.

(Response on my idea request in GitHub:
https://github.com/Azure/bicep/discussions/7043#discussioncomment-2978469)

Answer (score 1):

**Tested in my enviorment and found that you can not use like below format to get that latest images from container registry. You have to use the full image name with tag to use thelatest/spefic image.**

> - br:myregistry.azurecr.io/bicep/myappmodule:v1.*
> - br:myregistry.azurecr.io/bicep/myappmodule:v1*
> - br:myregistry.azurecr.io/bicep/myappmodule:v1:latest
> - br:myregistry.azurecr.io/bicep/myappmodule:latest

**Pushed two images to ACR with simillar name ie you are using and for example trying to create a container instance from that images(resides in container registry)**

[image]

**Getting an error since the image is trying to pull to create a container instance doesn't exist with that name**.

[image]

**Tried with the full name as it is in container registry it works fine.**

[image]

**would suggest you please use below format as it is pushed to conatainer registry.**

- myregistry.azurecr.io/bicep/myappmodule:v1.0.25798
- myregistry.azurecr.io/bicep/myappmodule:v1.0.25799

Comment: Thank you. It also works for me when I set the whole version. I was hoping to find a solution where we can reference the major version so we don't have to go to all the files that reference the modules and change to the new "build/fix" ID. This way we can make minor changes to the shared modules without having to change the referencing sources every time. Thanks a lot for your effort though!